# Is there a way to digitally zoom a Nikon D-90 recording video in 720p?

Tags: zoom, nikon-d90, video, digital-zoom

While using the Nikon D-90 Live-View mode to record video in 720p, is there a way to pick the pixels from the center of the sensor?  In other words, the sensor on the D-90 is way more than 720 lines of sensor input, so could I get a zoom effect by picking the 720 lines from the center of the sensor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video mode is a program in the D90 that obviously either downscales sensor data or ignores/alternates entire sensor lines. As long as you can't change this program the higher resolution of the input won't be of any help to you.

AFAIK either an official update from Nikon (hell freezing over) or a hacked firmware are necessary to change the program of the current "video mode" to make your wish happen.